# tf.signal.rfft2d output shape?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, signal-processing, fft

Currently I'm trying to work on implementing a [Fourier CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.12621).

The first step for me is to understand the output shape generated by the [real fourier transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/rfft2d).

I have some code snippets below:

```
input = Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
f = Lambda(lambda x: tf.signal.rfft2d(x))(input)
print(f.shape, f.dtype)
# > (None, 150, 150, 2) <dtype: 'complex64'>
```

Where does the last dimension: 2 come from?  Shouldn't the output still have three channels resulting in (None, 150, 150, 3)?

I tried another fft_length to see if it would shed some light for me, but it has left me more confused than I was when I started

```
input = Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
f = Lambda(lambda x: tf.signal.rfft2d(x, fft_length=[100, 100]))(input)
print(f.shape, f.dtype)
# > (None, 150, 100, 51) <dtype: 'complex64'>
```

My question is primarily:
where does the shape (None, 150, 150, 2) come from?

as a bonus I'd love to also understand why the second code snippet results in (None, 150, 100, 51)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Luke, 2 is from 3/2+1 Please see the following quote from the doc: Since the DFT of a real signal is Hermitian-symmetric, RFFT2D only returns the fft_length / 2 + 1 unique components of the FFT for the inner-most dimension of output: the zero-frequency term, followed by the fft_length / 2 positive-frequency terms. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/rfft2d

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve my question through some additional testing.

It looks like you need to ensure that additional channels must be on the innermost dimension.  I've been able to get the code above to work with the following modifications:

```
def fft_on_axis(x):
    x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 3,  1, 2],)
    x_fft = tf.signal.rfft2d(x)
    result = tf.transpose(x_fft, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])
    return result

i = Input(shape=(150, 150, 3), name='Input')
x = Lambda(fft_on_axis, name='fft2d')(i)
print(x.shape)
> (None, 150, 76, 3)
```

This lines up with what I'd expect from the documentation!  The fft_length on the second dimension is cut in half plus one for the zero frequency term.